# How to convert string returning from get text() to tuple?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

My tests are comparing two values to make sure value getting from locator should not be less or equal to expected value.

Expected value returning from `element.getText` method is `(0.00, 0.00)` and actual value is `(0.82, 0.43)`. These are tuples but `element.getText` method is returning string. If I use `get_attribute("innerHTML")` it's returning `(u'(', u'0', u'.', u'8', u'2', u',', u' ', u'0', u'.', u'4', u'3', u')')`

Not sure what to use, `element.getText` or `get_attribute("innerHTML")`?

Comment: This isn't a QA-specific problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494514/converting-string-to-tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just converta tuple to a string and compare them:

```
# Python3 code to convert tuple  
# into string 
def convertTuple(tup): 
    str =  ''.join(tup) 
    return str

# Driver code 
tuple = ('g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's') 
str = convertTuple(tuple) 
print(str)
```

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-tuple-to-a-string/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Neils van..I'm sorry abu this I will make sure to post relevant questions only.

Comment: Np Stack Exchange network is broad and has a lot of different sites with different topics. For you this is a testing question, while for others it is a programming question. Dont feel bad when we close it, just ask again on the right site :)